# October CMS - RainLab.Translate causing issues with RainLab.Blog

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm an amateur website developer working on my first ever professional project where I'm using the plugins [RainLab.Blog](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-blog) and [RainLab.Translate](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-translate) in an [October CMS](https://octobercms.com/) installation. Ever since I installed and configured the translation plugin, I'm unable to publish new articles where I'm getting an error message saying "The content field is required.", *tho I am able to update existing articles*.

I have noticed that by selecting a different language in the Title-field and Slug-Field, they show up empty for the new language, as expected. However, the content area does not and I am unable to re-write the article in any other language.

**New article, first language:**
[image: New blog post in October CMS using RainLab.Blog]

**Same article, different language:**
[image]

As you can see, the content field won't play ball.

If there is something more I can provide to clarify the issue or if anybody got some feedback, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: can yous share which build you are using?

Comment: October CMS: 2.0.12
RainLab.Blog: 1.5.0
RainLab.Translate: 1.8.6

Comment: hmm OctoberCMS 2.0 is subscription-based right ?

Comment: That is correct. I'm using the "Pay As You Go" plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe you need to update your OctoberCMS version as I checked with the latest version and did not face any issue, please check the attached video (if its what you are talking about)

```
OctoebrCMS Build Version : 2.0.17
Blog Plugin Version : 1.5.1
Tranlate Plugin Version : 1.9.0
```

[image]

may be you just need to update version as with new version may be they solved issues.

> To update OctoberCMS

```yaml
First  => php artisan october:update
Second => php artisan october:migrate
```

Then it should work.

It seems in Translation plugin version `1.8.7` they have fixed this issue.

```
1.8.7 => Fixes Markdown editor translation.
```

if any doubt please comment.